# Varios potenciómetros con Arduino y c++

Tags: c++, arduino

Buen día, tengo un problema para poder recibir datos de mas de un potenciómetro conectados a un arduino mega, ya que cuando envío los datos, éstos llegan de forma simultáneamente en una misma variable y no logro controlar cada valor que me llega de diferente potenciómetro.

El código del arduino lo tengo así:

```
float info[5];
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
} 
void loop() {
  for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    info[i]=analogRead(i);
    Serial.println(info[i],10);
  }
  delay(1);
```

uso println ya que no encontre otra manera de enviar los datos a c++ para poderlos usar por separado

El código que uso en c++ es:

```
char señales[52]="";
while (Arduino->IsConnected())
    {
        int n = Arduino->ReadData(señales, 10); // Recibe datos del Arduino serie.
        cout <<señales << endl; // Muestra en pantalla dato recibido.

    }
```

Pero no logro separar cada valor del potenciómetro que llega quisiera saber si ¿hay alguna manera de enviar un arreglo con los 5 potenciómetros y que en c++ pueda usar los datos de cada potenciómetro basado en la posición del arreglo, o de que otra manera podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola. necesariamente tiene que ser el código de esa manera? podría sugerir estructuras , pero antes de poner una respuesta útil me gustaría conocer si debe ser estrictamente así.

Comment: no necesariamente, lo que necesito es esperar las señales para poder graficarlas

Answer (score 0):

Analizemos el código:

**analogRead()**. Esta función retorna un entero entre 0 y 1023, pero el código lo recibe en un `float`.

**Identificación de las puertas.** Las puertas análogas en Arduino son se escriben A0, A1, ... A5. El código usa enteros 0, 1, ... que **no** lo mismo.

**Configuración de las puertas.** Los puertos hay que abrirlos antes de usarlos.

Finalmente:

```
int info[5];
int ports[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3, A4};
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    pinMode(ports[i], INPUT);
  }
} 
void loop() {
  char linea[80];
  
  for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    info[i]=analogRead(ports[i]);
  }
  sprintf(linea, "%4d %4d %4d %4d %4d\n", info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4]);
  Serial.print(linea);  
  delay(1001);
}
```

Modifique el ciclo en `loop` para que lea correctamente la puerta análoga.

Las lecturas se acumulan en `info`, y una vez leidos los 5 valores, armo una línea con `sprintf` para mandar las 5 lecturas de una vez.

Produce:

```
 395  400  386  385  389
 375  382  370  369  376
 383  390  381  382  387
 404  410  401  404  406
 403  410  400  401  403
 383  389  379  379  381
 368  374  364  365  369
 379  387  377  379  383
```

Cada linea lleva cinco lecturas, separadas por espacios y terminadas con '\n'.